# Dynamic Delete query

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, nullpointerexception, resultset

Im trying to make a dynamic Delete Query.

What im basically trying to do is first grab the name of the first column in any table (the primary key). Then i use that in Another Query to delete from that table though i get a nullpointerexception?

Ohh and the primary key is not an INT like 1,2,3,4,5 etc.. it's formed up as S1,S2,S3,S4,S5 etc and has the type TEXT.

```
 Connection c = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try {
  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
  c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
  c.setAutoCommit(true);
  System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tablename);
  ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
  FirstColumn = rsmd.getColumnName(1);
  String query = "DELETE FROM "+tablename+" WHERE " +FirstColumn+ " = " +row;
  stmt = c.createStatement();

  stmt.executeUpdate(query);

  stmt.close();
  c.close();
```

Comment: Apostrophes around `row` in string `query`?

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: In general a stacktrace would show the line raising the NullPointerException and probably the exact variable being null.

Comment: My SQL injection alert meter is jumping around like crazy.

Comment: Dont worry this is school assignment for beginners so sql injection is not something i have to be aware of as of now, and yes i do know that i should use preparedstatements instead lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that all the variables you are using have been initialized.

I added single quotes around the FirstColumn name.

```
Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
      c.setAutoCommit(true);
      System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tablename);
      ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
      FirstColumn = rsmd.getColumnName(1);
      String query = "DELETE FROM "+ tablename +" WHERE " + FirstColumn + " = '" + row + "'";
      stmt = c.createStatement();

      stmt.executeUpdate(query);

      stmt.close();
      c.close();
```

If you are still getting an error you should try printing out your row name and see what it prints out.

Edit: Since you are new stylistically it's preferable to add a single space when using operators to improve code readability.  For example 1+3+x+34 is a lot harder to read than 1 + 3 + x + 34.  Granted there is no "wrong" code style but improving code readability is always a plus.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your `stmt` object...

```
stmt = c.createStatement();
```

before executing the query.

Comment: No you don't. You create statement **after** executing first query. You must do this **before** executing first query.